# Api access using OAuth in cakephp

Tags: php, api, cakephp, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I am using an OAuth plugin for cakephp (thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server) which am having some issues with at them moment.

I want to be able to allow access to my cakephp Rest with two calls

provision - This just adds in a Client id into my table
auth - using grant_type password I send over grant_type, username, password and client_id and return a access token.

Both these actions seem to be in working order and I am getting an access token back the problem is after I gain access I am still being kicked out by cakephp and redirected to the login page when I try an access one of the rest actions.

For example once I have an access key I send up a request to http://customer-server-2.dev/api/documents.json?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

At this point I should have access because the access token is correct and works fine - but I don't I get redirected to the login in page.

If anyone can help me with this I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two problems

1. Your access token may be expired.Get a new access token and check
2. Check your scope when you are getting access token

Comment: The access token is fine and still in date - however the scope comes back as null

Comment: Just looked into scope and yes that was the problem so thank you very much for that! :)